# How to extract x,y coordinates from OpenCV "cv2.keypoint" object?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I tried to use the following code:

```
    xCoordinate=point.x
```

(The point is a type of `cv2.keyPoint`)
It gives me an error saying `cv2.keyPoint` has no attribute 'x'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

pts = np.float([key_point.pt for key_point in kp]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
```

`pts` will be an `array` of keypoints.

Answer (score 24):

`point.pt is a tuple`(x,y)`.

So,

```
x = point.pt[0]
y = point.pt[1]
```

or,

```
(x,y) = point.pt
```

Comment: Where can this be found in the documentation?

Answer (score 14):

OpenCV provides a function for this. You can run:

```
pts = cv2.KeyPoint_convert(kp)
```

Answer (score 8):

[Read the docs.](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html)

## class KeyPoint

Data structure for salient point detectors.

- Point2f pt
  -- coordinates of the keypoint
- float size
  -- diameter of the meaningful keypoint neighborhood
- float angle ...¶

So `point.pt` is a Point2f.

Try `x,y= point.pt`

Comment: `point.pt.x` is invalid, please correct it as: `x, y = point.pt`

Answer (score 4):

Here is my take (runable code):

```
import cv2, os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# INITIALISATION
filename = os.path.join('foo', 'bar.jpg')
img0 = cv2.imread(filename) # original image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() # initialize SIFT 
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2) # create subplots

# DETECT AND DRAW KEYPOINTS
# sift.detect() returns a list of keypoints
# keypoint is a standard class of opencv (not just SIFT-related)
kp = sift.detect(gray,None) # calculates SIFT points
img1=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp, None) # mae new image with keypoints drawn
ax1.imshow(img1) # plot 

# RETREIVE KEYPOINTS COORDINATES AND DRAW MANUALLY
# Reade these and make numpy array
pts = np.asarray([[p.pt[0], p.pt[1]] for p in kp])
cols = pts[:,0]
rows = pts[:,1]
ax2.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
ax2.scatter(cols, rows)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved your problem like this.

```
kp,des = surf.detectAndCompute(img,None) 
pts = [p.pt for p in kp]
```

Now you get a list of x,y co-ordinates for all keypoints in your image.

Answer (score 0):

to get the correct shape for optical flow input I used a combination of the above

```
kp = sift.detect(old_frame, None)
pts0 = cv2.KeyPoint.convert(kp).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
```